# How to convert an instance of a class to a string and then back to that class instance?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, class, oop

I have a class instance that I am converting to a string (in order to send to AWS SQS). On my SQS worker, I want to receive this string and convert it back to the instance of the class. Is this possible?

I can easily use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to handle the variables, but how can I use the methods after I have reinitialized the instance?

Comment: Does your class do anything in its constructor?

Comment: Only initializes variables